# Drawing using variables for easy modification

Tags: autocad

What is the method to draw diagrams in autocad with variable dimensions such that the diagram will change depending on the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about parametric dimensions.

[Here's an article from Autodesk](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-899E008D-B422-4DF2-AC8D-1A4F5701ED4E-htm.html) that might get you started.